# What image format for an App for iPad, created through Adobe Flash?

Tags: flash, ipad, graphics

What format should I make images into, for an App for iPad?

(Each image will be a full page of a children's picture book. I'll create a Flash CS4 movie of the book and then convert the movie to an App for iPad.)

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would be PNG. It works well with Flash, is lossless, and supports transparency (should that become necessary).